# Who is Jambavan an incarnation of?

Tags: ramayana

[Jambavan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jambavan) an under appreciated character in the Ramayana(most people focus on Hanuman but it should be made clear it is Jambavan who made Hanuman aware of his immense spiritual prowess) is a steadfast devotee of Sr Rama. But is it mentioned anywhere that he is an incarnation of [Himavat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himavat) ?

So who is Jambavan's root deity ?

Answer (score 9):

There is no root deity of Jambavan. Every Vanara was created by some deity taking inspiration from Jambavan himself. Jambavan was created suddenly from Brahma's yawn.

From [Valmiki Ramayana Bala Kanda Sarga 17](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga17/bala_17_frame.htm) (Translated by Desiraju Hanumanta Rao & K. M. K. Murthy)

> pūrvameva mayā sṛṣṭo jāṃbavānṛkṣapuṅgavaḥ |
>   jṛṃbhamāṇasya sahasā mama vakrādajāyata || 1-17-7
>
> te tathoktā bhagavatā tat pratiśrutya śāsanam |
>   janayāmāsurevaṃ te putrān vānararūpiṇaḥ || 1-17-8
>
> "I have already created the eminent bear Jambavanta in earlier times, as he suddenly came forth from my yawning face. [1-17-7]
>
> When Brahma addressed them thus, those gods have agreed to his order and accordingly started to parent sons in the resemblance of monkeys. [1-17-8]